# Windows 10 SSL certificate verif failed

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate

My error appeared today (before it worked fine). I have SSL cert verification failure. I've updated libraries to newest versions according to solutions from web:

```
Python 3.6.5

certifi==2018.8.24
requests==2.19.1
urllib3==1.23
```

Maybe cert is outdated somehow? (I have no knowledge)

OS:
Win 10
Repaetability:
100%

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 810, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 325, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\htrela\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "C:\Users\htrela\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\htrela\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\htrela\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 630, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e)
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)
```

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Modules/_ssl.c#L833 sounds like SSL/TLS handshake failed, where you need a tool like Wireshark to further troubleshoot.

Comment: It was an isue with server. New cert was improper.

Comment: post your findings as an answer and accept it.

Comment: The certificate may have simply expired, have you looked at the certificate properties?

Answer (score 0):

The certificate may have simply expired, have you looked at the certificate properties? – Robert Aug 31 at 18:01

Yes, that was the case, however I couldn't check it by myself. Person responsible answered me with confirmation.